# iso c++ forbids declaration of generic with no type

Tags: c++, generics

My native language is C#, so when I started using C++, I wanted to create the get/set sugar syntax for library consumers available in C#.

So I wrote...

```
template<typename T>
class GetProperty
{
    private:
        T (*get)();
    public:
        GetProperty(T (*get)())
        {
            this->get = get;
        }
        operator T()
        {
            return get();
        }
        template<typename S, typename T>
        GetProperty<S> operator=(GetProperty<T> fool)
        {
            throw 0;
        }
 };
```

Then, to to use this, I wrote the code:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
    private:
        struct LinkItem
        {
            public:
                T* Item;
                LinkItem* Next;
                                GetProperty<int> Length (&getLength);
                LinkItem(T* Item = NULL, int length = 1, LinkItem* Next = NULL)
                {
                    this->Item = Item;
                    this->length = length;
                    this->Next = Next;
                }
                LinkItem& operator =(LinkItem rhs)
                {
                    this->Item = rhs.Item;
                    this->length = rhs.length;
                    this->Next = rhs.Next;
                    return *this;
                }
            private:
                 int length;
                 int getLength()
                 {
                     return length;
                 }
        };
        LinkItem* current;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

However, the C/C++ addition on Netbeans (I believe this is the g++ compiler) claims I am instantiating GetProperty with no type.
According to a Google search, this happens if someone forgets a using statement, or to include a header, etc.
But int is a primitive, so this can't be.
What's going on?

Comment: This code doesn't compile at all: http://ideone.com/qfH21

Comment: "when I started using C++, I wanted to create the get/set sugar syntax for library consumers available in C#." You should, at all times, *resist* the temptation to try to port idioms from one language to another. It would be better to find a way to use C++ as C++, not as a variation of C#. C++ doesn't have properties, so you shouldn't create that concept. Approach each language for what it is, not for what you think it ought to be.

Comment: Similarly, don't rebuild `std::list` (and doubly so, if you're rebuilding it, don't call it *`Vector`*. That's just confusing). Just use the actual C++ standard library type.

Comment: Very cool article on imitating properties in C++ http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/A_3843-How-to-add-properties-to-standard-C-classes.html by a smart guy.  I wouldn't bother, but if you decide it's what you want they probably already did it there.

Comment: Initialize it in the ctor initializer list `: Length(getLength)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the fact that VC++ doesn't implement non-static data member initializers, you can't treat the member function getLength as an `int (*)()`. Its type is `int (LinkItem::*)()`.

```
struct Foo {
    int foo(void) {return 1;}
};

int main() {
    int (*var)() = &Foo::foo; // Error
    int (Foo::*var)() = &Foo::foo; // Okay
}
```

You probably shouldn't be trying to import a foreign idiom like this, but if you really want to you can try something like the following. (Though as Nicol Bolas points out, you also probably shouldn't be implementing your own linked list, or naming it 'vector'. If you're learning C++ just learn the C++ way before going and trying to reinvent things.)

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class GetProperty
{
private:
    std::function<int()> get;
public:
    GetProperty(std::function<int()> get)
        : get(get)
    {}
    operator T()
    {
        return get();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
private:
    struct LinkItem
    {
    public:
        T* Item;
        LinkItem* Next;
        GetProperty<int> Length;
        LinkItem(T* Item = NULL, int length = 1, LinkItem* Next = NULL)
            : Length([this] { return this->getLength(); })
        {
...
```

Comment: True.  I just wnated to write a linked-list to get a sense of the algorithms, and I find writing get_Variable and set_Variable calls annoying, as they add typing without adding meaning.
I certainly shouldn't try to import something like this though.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing GetProperty object while declaring it in a struct. That is not allowed in C++. You have to move the construction to the constructor.

Comment: It's allowed in C++11, but VC++ doesn't implement it yet.